# How to define a global variable in a Cocoa Framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

When you build a Cocoa App, you can add all the global methods and objects in `AppDelegate` class, and in any place of the code, you can get access to `AppDelegate` via

```
AppDelegate* appDlgt = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

But how can I do the same thing in a Cocoa Framework? It doesn't seem to have `AppDelegete`

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, that's really bad programming practice.

Comment: @TheKraken OK... what is the recommended programming practice, please?

Comment: I suggest this : http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: it is no more evil than a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
+ (instancetype)sharedMyClass
{
    static id           kSharedMyClass = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t      theOnceToken;
    dispatch_once( &theOnceToken, ^{ kSharedMyClass = [[self alloc] init]; } );
    return kSharedMyClass;
}
```

Comment: A google search leads me to http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMObjectSingleton.h

Answer (score 1):

NSApp is the shortcut to your NSApplication instance, which normally have a delegate, or more archaically, a subclass where you could store data.

so if you followed the default project template:

```
((YourAppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate]).property
```

will get you where you want to go

don't abuse this, as you should only really store things that belong to the application in the delegate, and even then, those user defined properties should be NSUserDefaults or contained in some other controller class.

edit: sorry, I kind of missed the point....
if you need higher level application data to be passed down into a framework, then you can do so many things, with out knowing the specifics it would be hard to comment on which would be best...

some options:

define a protocol in the framework with the properties you are interested in, the adopt that protocol in your delegate.

then `((id <FrameworkProtocol>)NSApp.delegate).protoProperty`would work.

but that introduces a requirement that the delegate adopts that protocol, which you can check with the conformsToProtocol: method.